# ExpressEngine : Custom query - Grouping entries daily

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have following query which groups and counts entries for each day :

```
SELECT DISTINCT `year`, `month`, `day`, count(entry_id) as 'posts'
FROM (`exp_channel_titles`)
WHERE `status` =  'open'
GROUP BY `year`, `month`, `day`
ORDER BY `entry_date` desc
```

it works fine however it selects from all categories but I want to limit to one or more category.

for people who are not familiar with EE database, here is few example from tables which we may need

exp_channel_titles:

```
entry_id year month day
1 2011 11 5
2 2011 11 6
3 2011 11 7
```

exp_categories:

```
cat_id cat_name
1 sport
2 computer
3 car
```

exp_category_posts:  which connects entries to categories

```
entry_id cat_id
1 2
1 2
2 1
3 3
```

Comment: What do you mean by limit to one or more categories ? And why there is  a duplication in your exp_category_posts (typo?) ?

Comment: duplication ? where ? /// each entry in EE may assigns to one or more category, for example you post a car news and connect its to car category ... my example query doesn't check entries's category and select from categories but I want to add a condition which it checks select only from categories which I want , for example I want to select entries from computer category , first I need to find category ID then select entries which are connected to that category ( table exp_category_posts)

Comment: the 1st and 2nd line in exp_category_posts.

Comment: oops! yes it was typo .. anyway ajreal's answer is what I am was looking for .. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ect.year, ect.month, ect.day, count(ect.entry_id) as posts
FROM exp_channel_titles as ect
INNER JOIN exp_category_posts ecp
  ON ecp.entry_id=ect.entry_id
INNER JOIN exp_categories ec
  ON ecp.cat_id=ec.cat_id
WHERE ect.status = 'open' 
  AND ec.cat_name = "computer" /* this is to filter by category name */
GROUP BY ect.year, ect.month, ect.day
ORDER BY ect.entry_date desc;  /* where is this entry_date come from? */
```